# Typescript union type for keys, infer type for dictionary values

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I am trying to write a type which expresses the below without needing to explicitly create a type for the translations dictionary.

```
type Language = "english" | "german" | "french";

const translations = {
  english: {
    foo: "foo",
    bar: "bar"
  },
  german: {
    foo: "föö"
  }
};
```

I have come up with this

```
type Translations = {english: T, } & {[key in Language]?: Partial<T>};
```

but this doesn't quite satisfy my requirements, as `T` still needs to be passed to the type parameter...

Comment: What's that `enum a` doing in there?

Comment: And... what do you want to do with your `Translations` type?  There's no specific type in TypeScript that represents your intended type, which would require *existentially quantified generic type parameters*, a feature not present in TS (request at [microsoft/TypeScript#14466](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14466)).  So all we can do is work around it, and for that, I'd like to see some use cases.

Comment: Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/WP5DLw) workaround work for you?  Here we keep `Translations<T>` generic in `T`, and use a helper function so that you don't have to manually pass in `T`.  If so, let me know and I'll write up an answer.  If not, please consider showing some code examples where it wouldn't work for your uses.

Comment: That worked perfectly. My use case is for snippet that I'm using for a react project: https://pastebin.com/XcNmaEiE

This already worked, but I didn't have type checking for the translations object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript cannot express `Translations` as a specific type.  What you'd need is a different sort of generic type that most languages with generics doesn't have: a so-called *existentially quantified generic type*, or sometimes just *existential type*.  In your `Translations` type, you have a type parameter `T`... but you don't want to have to specify it.  Instead, you want to say "the person who supplies a `Translations` value should be allowed to specify `T` to whatever they want; all I care or know about is that such a `T` *exists*."  Maybe such a type definition would look like this:

```
/* NOT SUPPORTED
type Translations = <exists T extends Record<keyof T, string>>(
  { english: T } & { [K in Language]?: Partial<T> }
);
*/
```

But of course, you can't do this.  There is no `exists` keyword in TypeScript and no direct method to quantify generic type parameters this way.  There's a feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#14466](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14466) for existential types, but it's not clear if that feature will ever be implemented.

There are ways to *emulate* existential types in TypeScript, but they are a bit convoluted and strange to use.  Instead of trying to do this, let's give up on existential types and instead look at possible workarounds.

---

The most straightforward workaround is to define `Translations<T>` as a generic *constraint* on the type, with a type parameter `T`:

```
type Translations<T extends Record<keyof T, string>> = 
  { english: T } & { [K in Language]?: Partial<T> };
```

To avoid requiring the user to specify `T` in a type annotation, you can make a helper function:

```
const asTranslations = <T extends Record<keyof T, string>>(
  translations: Translations<T>) => translations;
```

This *identity function* just returns its input, so at runtime it's essentially a no-op.  But by constraining the input to `Translations<T>`, we are asking the compiler to *infer* the generic type `T` from the input.  If the call compiles with no errors, then we know that the input is valid:

```
const translations = asTranslations({
    english: {
        foo: "foo",
        bar: "bar"
    },
    german: {
        foo: "föö"
    }
}); // okay
/* const translations: Translations<{
  foo: string;
  bar: string;
}> */
```

Here the compiler has inferred that `T` is `{foo: string, bar: string}` and therefore `translations` is inferred to be of type `Translations<{foo: string, bar: string}>`.

If you make a mistake, the compiler will warn you about it:

```
const badTranslations = asTranslations({
    english: {
        foo: "foo",
        bar: "bar"
    },
    german: {
        foo: "föö",
        baz: "baß" // error!
    //  ~~~~~~~~~~
    // Type '{ foo: string; baz: string; }' is not assignable 
    //    to type Partial<{ foo: string; bar: string; }>' 
    // Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'baz' 
    //    does not exist in type 'Partial<{ foo: string; bar: string; }>'
    }
});
```

In this case too, the compiler infers `{foo: string; bar: string}` for `T`.  But this time, there is an [excess property warning](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks) on the `baz` property of `german`, because `baz` is neither `foo` nor `bar`.

(Note that excess property warnings only happen with object literals. If you need to copy your object literal to a variable before calling `asTranslations()` on it, you won't get the warning.  If that use case is important, you can switch to a different definition for `Translations<T>`, but I won't bother going into that here unless there's some need for it.  It's in the linked Playground Code example below anyway.)

---

One side effect of this workaround is that you will be required to make anything that deals with a `Translations<T>` type generic itself.  You can plausibly free up end users from having to specify `T`, but your code base will still end up dragging around an extra type parameter.  For example, a function which ideally would look like `function saveTranslations(translations: Translations, filename: string): void {}` will now look like `function saveTranslations<T extends Record<keyof T, string>>(translations: Translations<T>, filename: string): void {}`.

For that reason, it might be best to only require such a generic type in a validation function that accepts the input, and then in your internal library code you widen the type to something less accurate but easier to use:

```
function userFacingFunction<T extends Record<keyof T, string>>(
  translations: Translations<T>) {
    internalLibraryFunction(translations);
}

type AnyTranslations = Translations<Record<string, string>>;
// not generic anymore
function internalLibraryFunction(translations: AnyTranslations) {
    // do something 
}
```

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-WRcE0y6xx5S3jQomR+cpyRhhXgl4F8LjSFsDW64ut59KloU+Rmkfkql0nYsrVWpEyqVir1WjVz7brE1OXetJeOt1n-k5LVAS4y8q4zIgHkkxQJWnjeKOW4Tghbo3C0bRXjGcaElED59gOSDYZoVSJsSpKRLBXhFPIe6bm61y7pOB5ockJ5-Mxd6-terg5G+97FI+5Rvq+oyRA0iBniJ+Scew-63t+UBFAAXo+AD7lA8tEdB0AyACEvFaBpUAAH4maZZn6ZoGnzE6ADkXycZhyC8ApcDKXhWG4jZ0IhAgrjViQJBEEgogFAQ0CmvKuiFsWqH6u07lOS5JQJQRuKvF5FmgVAswFAAVgGXjEN6PgqEwIBQO4BDlZIAZEGw5WMr5ADusJgNpuqBBIUZKlANlKV58iuBIUC+V4DxPNmxy9dFRBYvZ8WOaluGLc5xE2UJgwEmRLhrlATVwEQXhhG+rESfJcVXpk3Fyd+uE4GUAH9DdURiZ+7GtNJXQ9M9rRKapj1REBWjlqMFGagwDD0bWjFuu8+2HSBGkoGQFVkKSeQGggRqilAKAkFYABi0hxgThrGs2Xo+u2gZdhAYYRvMUaLUOG4Nh4SH7ihbyzu9WgwsVogEDARAFD4dAgKTWPGsOMPBFtozko6ugAIIICANFs9uzrIcENz+jTNyLUz-ZxgmhFZaNtrSrGcqICADAMhAGNkzj-NWILwui8UEsu+4Ms6+zUCq+rsseDzb4aYN0auOIwBkHGUCDKSiuCJSEhSDIUD0kyLJsvIABMnJQby-KCgHIQSlK9qRYq7KamqGpajqVqY9j7jaGaMKWnqcfQFXNtK2XnO64sLZU5mUIwjmCIQCiCSuHlBVpaEb5fFmU-dgziIJFCY9ttPhhQMimZrNmm--JCiLbwWnqtr6UDn-MYI2axNmIkfKVQAk0rqnqgLfxAX+uJVxVnFNDcu1wKZ3xeKHd0bwPisyXGmWcmB5ywJXKDXaiCtxQw1kuQ8klNCnS-PJT6N5Mp3QekJH6WhXpnVIfFGSPQNoK0RmBCCUEphg2wW6DmtFda8wcibJyR5lrCIIoMEiJIuQ7VAVRPBOCdzgOHh4AhrRiG8wvIwy8PFCE4X4rgKhejhKtDoSQ78n1ZIUNcv9LKVhtJ0D0no7kvJjJmXcZlKytl5oYXEc5P6KVVpeVICNPyYDArBTgKFcKZopozTmhdBIK0kpJL8WlDKziDK8hyvlI0UAipWGUHyOA5VKrVUgFwOqDVmqtXalYTqJBup1z6q5AaQ0fJhPGnBKeU0bLxJLD41J+F-EGOSWtFhwEMHkV2vDI65iogaMymQ661jkr3SfNQt8ZjNHoT-N9axbl1lqQmcDc2YMyAQ1wbAuGB1gBsM0g4nS-wbTHBCD2Gyr0AB0-VxScHNG4BgUhAjRIUhAYATUID4GtBIcKCoSDJyAA)